# Setting up location with type in NEST Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have the following elastic index item:

```
{
        "_index": "areas",
        "_type": "area",
        "_id": "AVb_MPXHCPQmPhMEnjGo",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Chorlton somewhere",
          "location": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
              -2.2852634,
              53.4417472
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

Now in NEST my class looks like:

```
[String]
public string Name { get; set; }

[GeoPoint]
public GeoLocation Location{ get; set; }
```

I want to be able to represent Location in C# with a type and co-ordinates.

I know this is wrong, however I don't know how to achieve the structure of the JSON above in the class structure in C#

Comment: You should try `GeoShape` instead of `GeoLocation` as your `location` point is not a `geo_point` but a `geo_shape`.

Comment: @Val if I set the attribute of the property to GeoShape, what type do I need to use for the property in that case?

Comment: In your case, `PointGeoShape` I guess

Comment: Ah, I was looking for Geo... at the start. That looks to be working!

Comment: Cool, glad it is working!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your JSON, you have a `geo_shape` and not a `geo_point`, so your `Location` field declaration should look like this instead

```
[GeoShape]
public PointGeoShape Location{ get; set; }
```